# Trouble with sorting numberic values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, array-multisort

Update - I've fixed key names. Here is my new code. I've gotten each sort to work correctly if I comment out the previous sort. If the previous sort runs the following sort will not function properly. Why does this happen and how can I resolve it?

```
<?php
$poptable=array(
    array('State' => 'Alabama',
    'Capital' => 'Montgomery',
    'pop2010' => 4779736,
    'poprank' => 23),

    array('State' => 'Alaska',
    'Capital' => 'Juneau',
    'pop2010' => 710231,
    'poprank' => 47),

    array('State' => 'Arizona',
    'Capital' => 'Phoenix',
    'pop2010' => 6329017,
    'poprank' => 18),

    array('State' => 'Arkansas',
    'Capital' => 'Little Rock',
    'pop2010' => 2915918,
    'poprank' => 32),

    array('State' => 'California',
    'Capital' => 'Sacramento',
    'pop2010' => 37253956,
    'poprank' => 1),

    array('State' => 'Colorado',
    'Capital' => 'Denver',
    'pop2010' => 5029196,
    'poprank' => 22),

    array('State' => 'Connecticut',
    'Capital' => 'Hartford',
    'pop2010' => 3518288,
    'poprank' => 29),

    array('State' => 'Delaware',
    'Capital' => 'Dover',
    'pop2010' => 897934,
    'poprank' => 45),

    array('State' => 'Florida',
    'Capital' => 'Tallahassee',
    'pop2010' => 18801301,
    'poprank' => "4"),

    array('State' => 'Georgia',
    'Capital' => 'Atlanta',
    'pop2010' => 9687653,
    'poprank' => 9),

    array('State' => 'Hawaii',
    'Capital' => 'Boise',
    'pop2010' => 1360301,
    'poprank' => 42));

//Read column data into rows
foreach ($poptable as $key => $row)
    {
    $state[$key] = $row['State'];
    $capital[$key] = $row['Capital'];
    $pop2010[$key] = $row['pop2010'];
    $poprank[$key] = $row['poprank'];
    }

//foreach ($poptable as $row) {
//      foreach ($row as $key => $value){
//              ${$key}[] = $value;}}

echo "<pre>";

//Sort data by state name in ascending order
array_multisort($state, SORT_ASC, $poptable);
//Output sorted data
print_r($poptable);
echo "<hr>";

//Sort data by capital in descending order
array_multisort($capital, SORT_DESC, $poptable);
//Output sorted data
print_r($poptable);
echo "<hr>";

//Sort data by population in ascending order
array_multisort($pop2010, SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC, $poptable);
//Output sorted data
print_r($poptable);
echo "<hr>";

//Sort data by population rank in descending order
array_multisort($poprank, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $poptable);
//OUTPUT sorted data
print_r($poptable);

echo "</pre>";

?>
```

I'm trying to sort a multidimensional array. However array_multisort isn't working as I thought it would. I have to use array_multisort. My first two sorts work correctly (the state and capital sorts). What's not sorting properly is the numeric values for pop2010 and poprank keys. I've tried making them strings, numbers, etc. My output for the sorted numeric values doesn't seem to be in any real order.
Here is my array.

```
$poptable=array(
    array('State' => 'Alabama',
    'Capital' => 'Montgomery',
    'pop2010' => 4779736,
    'poprank' => "23"),

    array('State' => 'Alaska',
    'Capital' => 'Juneau',
    'pop2010' => 710231,
    'poprank' => "47"),

    array('State' => 'Arizona',
    'Capital' => 'Phoenix',
    'pop2010' => 6329017,
    'poprank' => "18"),

    array('State' => 'Arkansas',
    'Capital' => 'Little Rock',
    'pop2010' => 2915918,
    'poprank' => "32"),

    array('State' => 'California',
    'Capital' => 'Sacramento',
    'pop2010' => 37253956,
    'poprank' => "1"),

    array('State' => 'Colorado',
    'Capital' => 'Denver',
    'pop2010' => 5029196,
    'poprank' => "22"),

    array('State' => 'Connecticut',
    'Capital' => 'Hartford',
    'pop2010' => 3518288,
    'poprank' => "29"),

    array('State' => 'Delaware',
    'Capital' => 'Dover',
    'pop2010' => 897934,
    'poprank' => "45"),

    array('State' => 'Florida',
    'Capital' => 'Tallahassee',
    'pop2010' => '18,801,301',
    'poprank' => '4'),

    array('State' => 'Georgia',
    'Capital' => 'Atlanta',
    'pop2010' => '9,687,653',
    'poprank' => '9'),

    array('State' => 'Hawaii',
    'Capital' => 'Boise',
    'pop2010' => '1,360,301',
    'poprank' => '42'));

echo "<pre>"
//Sort data by state name in ascending order
array_multisort($State, SORT_ASC, $poptable);
//Output sorted data
print_r($poptable);
echo "<hr>";

//Sort data by capital in descending order
array_multisort($Capital, SORT_DESC, $poptable);
//Output sorted data
print_r($poptable);
echo "<hr>";

//Sort data by population
array_multisort($poprank, SORT_STRING, SORT_DESC, $poptable);
//Output sorted data
print_r($poptable);
echo "<hr>";

echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: your array keys are also different 2010 pop / pop2010

Comment: Ya I caught that. I've fixed the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
array_multisort($key1, SORT_ASC, $key2, SORT_DESC, $arrayname);
```